# Toast Notification fails with "Value does not fall within expected range" on Windows 8.1

Tags: notifications, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1, toast

I have Windows 8.1 Store app, I get Toast Notifications failed when I try to show them. But they work fine on Windows 10 though.

I've downloaded Sample app for Toast Notification from MSDN. It doesn't work too.
I've written my own sample:

```
private void SendToast()
{
    var toastXml =
    @"<toast>
       <visual>
           <binding template=""ToastImageAndText02"">
               <image id=""1"" src=""image1"" alt=""image1""/>
               <text id=""1"">Toast header</text>
               <text id=""2"">Toast body</text>
           </binding>  
       </visual>

    var xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDocument.LoadXml(toastXml);

    var notification = new ToastNotification(xmlDocument);

    notification.Failed += OnNotificationFail;
    notification.Activated += OnNotificationActivated;
    notification.Dismissed += OnNotificationDismissed;

    ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().Show(notification);
}
```

And it doesn't work on Windows 8.1 too. But it works perfectly on Windows 10.

When I try to show notification I get Failed event fired.

args.ErrorCode looks like this:

```
{"Value does not fall within the expected range."}
    Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
    HResult: -2147024809
    HelpLink: null
    IPForWatsonBuckets: {0}
    InnerException: null
    IsTransient: false
    Message: "Value does not fall within the expected range."
    ParamName: null
    RemoteStackTrace: null
    Source: null
    StackTrace: null
    TargetSite: null
    WatsonBuckets: null
    _HResult: -2147024809
    _className: null
    _data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
    _dynamicMethods: null
    _exceptionMethod: null
    _exceptionMethodString: null
    _helpURL: null
    _innerException: null
    _ipForWatsonBuckets: {0}
    _message: "Value does not fall within the expected range."
    _remoteStackIndex: 0
    _remoteStackTraceString: null
    _safeSerializationManager: {System.Runtime.Serialization.SafeSerializationManager}
    _source: null
    _stackTrace: null
    _stackTraceString: null
    _watsonBuckets: null
    _xcode: -532462766
    _xptrs: {0}
    m_paramName: null
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your code in Windows 8.1 project but I'm not able to reproduce your error.

It can work well so I don't think there is issue in the sample code :

[image]

Please double-check your developing environment like if there's something missed in your Windows 8.1 SDK.

You might use another machine to test this feature on Windows 8.1 app. See also [Send a local toast notification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/tiles-and-notifications-send-local-toast).

Comment: As far as I see you run this project on Windows 10 machine. It works fine under Windows 10 (even though the project is designed for Windows 8.1)
But it didn't work under two Windows 8.1 machines